# Как заменить текстуру attenuation?

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры, текстура

Возникла необходимость изменить закон затухания света от Point. В качестве отправной точки взял тему [Easiest way to change Point Light attenuation ? (with Deferred path)](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/easiest-way-to-change-point-light-attenuation-with-deferred-path.254337/#post-1681835)
Сделал все по инструкции, правда версия Unity у меня 4.6 а не 4.5 как у автора. Все получилось, кроме одного: делаю через lookup texture подмену тектсуры. Обновил шейдер `Internal-PrePassLighting.shader` как было написано в инструкции. Если вношу в нем изменения  в расчет attenuation то вижу что картинка меняется. Добавил текстуру _LightTextureB02 и использую в шейдере ее вместо _LightTextureB0. Создавать и обновлять ее пытаюсь в скрипте на камере

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LightAttenuationManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Texture2D m_AttenTex = null;

    private float k0;
    private float k1;
    private float k2;

    public float K0
    {
        get { return k0; }
        set { k0 = value; RefreshAttenuation();}
    }

    public float K1
    {
        get { return k1; }
        set { k1 = value; RefreshAttenuation(); }
    }

    public float K2
    {
        get { return k2; }
        set { k2 = value; RefreshAttenuation(); }
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        k0 = 1;
        k1 = 0;
        K2 = 0;
        RefreshAttenuation();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void RefreshAttenuation()
    {
        //=== Point Light Attenutation
        m_AttenTex = new Texture2D(256, 1, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false, true);
        m_AttenTex.filterMode = FilterMode.Bilinear;
        m_AttenTex.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;
        Color[] AttenColor = new Color[256];

        for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
        {
            float v;

            if (i < 255)
            {
                v = i / 255.0f;
                v = 1.0f / (k0 + k1 * v + k2 * v * v);
            }
            else
                v = 0.0f;

            AttenColor[i] = new Color(v, v, v, v);
        }

        m_AttenTex.SetPixels(AttenColor);
        m_AttenTex.Apply();
        Shader.SetGlobalTexture("_LightTextureB02", m_AttenTex);
    }
}
```

Текстура создается, я вижу ее через редактор, но вот на самом источнике света это никак не сказывается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалось добиться требуемого эффекта, в чем была причина так и не разобрался. Повторил все шаги с самого начала, только делал их поменьше и каждый раз проверял что получилось.

1. Скачал из [Built-in shaders](http://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive) архив для своей версии Unity. Перенес  в Assets шейдер `Internal-PrePassLighting.shader` причем не в папку Resources как было в инструкции, а в свою Shader. Проверил что он подтягивается (исправил код шейдера, затем вернул его обратно)
2. В шейдере добавил строчки

> _LightTextureB0 ("", 2D) = "" {}// была
>
> _LightTextureB02 ("", 2D) = "" {}//добавил

далее

> sampler2D _LightTextureB0;//была
>
> sampler2D _LightTextureB02;//добавил

далее

> //float atten = tex2D (_LightTextureB0, att.rr).UNITY_ATTEN_CHANNEL; //закоментировал
>
> float atten = tex2D (_LightTextureB02, att.rr).UNITY_ATTEN_CHANNEL; //добавил

3. Немного подправил менеджер по управлению затуханием света

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class LightAttenuationManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Texture2D m_AttenTex = null;

    private float k0;
    private float k1;
    private float k2;

    public float K0
    {
        get { return k0; }
        set { k0 = value; RefreshAttenuation();}
    }

    public float K1
    {
        get { return k1; }
        set { k1 = value; RefreshAttenuation(); }
    }

    public float K2
    {
        get { return k2; }
        set { k2 = value; RefreshAttenuation(); }
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        k0 = 1;
        k1 = 0;
        K2 = 25;
        RefreshAttenuation();
    }

    public void RefreshAttenuation()
    {
        //=== Point Light Attenutation
        m_AttenTex = new Texture2D(256, 1, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false, true);
        m_AttenTex.filterMode = FilterMode.Bilinear;
        m_AttenTex.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;
        Color[] AttenColor = new Color[256];

        for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
        {
            float v;

            if (i < 255)
            {
                v = i / 255.0f;
                float r = (k0 + k1*v + k2*v*v);
                v = Math.Abs(r) < float.Epsilon?  1: Mathf.Clamp01(1.0f / r);

            }
            else
                v = 0.0f;

            AttenColor[i] = new Color(v, v, v, v);
        }

        m_AttenTex.SetPixels(AttenColor);
        m_AttenTex.Apply();
        Shader.SetGlobalTexture("_LightTextureB02", m_AttenTex);
    }
}
```

4. Сделал на сцене три ползунка через UI, связал их с переменными K0, K1, K2 у LightAttenuationManager.

Вот теперь все заработало. Дергаем ползунки меняется освещение.

Answer (score 0):

В Unity 5.0 процедура несколько другая. Здесь было существенно переписано освещение, при этом сохранены старые варианты отрисовки.

1. Скачал из [Built-in shaders](http://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive) архив для своей версии Unity. Перенес в Assets файлы `Internal-PrePassLighting.shader`, `Internal-DeferredShading.shader`, `UnityDeferredLibrary.cginc` причем не в папку `Resources` как было в инструкции, а в свою `Shader`.
2. Перешел к камере и выставил в ней `Rendering Path` в состояние `Defferesd`.
3. Для подмены текстуры использую тот же класс `LightAttenuationManager` (см. выше) добавил его на камеру
4. В файл `UnityDeferredLibrary.cginc` внес изменения как в посте ранее делал для `Internal-PrePassLighting.shader`, последний блок для секции с `#if defined (POINT) || defined (POINT_COOKIE)`
5. В меню `Edit -> Project Settings -> Graphics` выставил для поля `Deffered` состояние `Custom shader` и указал шейдер `Internal-DeferredShading.shader`. Для поля `Legacy Deferred` установил `Custom shader` и указал шейдер `Internal-PrePassLighting.shader`.
6. Перегрузил Unity. Настроил через UI доступ к переменным менеджера. Вот теперь все работает.

Comment: Добавлю, что для правильной работы собственных шейдеров, основанных на Built-In shaders, в скопированных шейдерах нужно подкручивать инклюды, иначе они будут смотреть на внутренние *.cginc файлы.
Также, некоторые шейдеры могут просто не использоваться в режиме камеры Orthographic.